# PHPUnit test shows failure even though everything is fine

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have a controller for adding languages to my database. Earlier in the controller's test class, the test for adding a new language adds a new language called "Test Language". I also have a test for the editing action, with the following code:

```
public function testCanEditLanguageAction()
    {
        $language = $this->em->getRepository('\Entities\Languages')
            ->findOneByEnglishName($this->testLanguage);
        $languageId = $language->getId();
        unset($language);

        $replacementName = 'Esttay Anguagelay';

        // get the form in order to get the hash
        $form = new Application_Model_FormLanguage([
            'action' => '/langauges/edit',
            'id' => $languageId
        ]);

        $this->dispatch("/languages/edit/$languageId");
        $form->render();

        $this->request
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setPost([
                'id' => $languageId,
                'englishName' => $replacementName,
                'japaneseName' => '仮の言葉',
                'kanaName' => 'カリノコトバ',
                'languageHash' => $form->languageHash->getValue()
            ]);

        $this->dispatch("/languages/edit");

        $this->assertRedirectTo('/');

        // make sure the data got edited properly
        $editedLanguage = $this->em
            ->getRepository('\Entities\Languages')
            ->findOneById($languageId);

        $this->assertEquals($replacementName, $editedLanguage->getEnglishName());
}
```

The test works fine for the most part: it correctly gets the language, edits it, and updates the value from "Test Language" to "Esttay Anguagelay". If I look in the database after the test is complete, the test language even has that value.

The problem is, according to PHPUnit, the test fails. I get the following output:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) LanguagesControllerTest::testCanEditLanguageAction
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-Esttay Anguagelay
+Test Language
```

In other words, it thinks that the langauge's value has not changed, when it clearly has. (Like I said, checking the database's value confirms that it has in fact changed).  Am I missing something here? I'm quite new to PHPUnit, so there may be something that I forgot to do or that I've done wrong.

Comment: Is there any sort of caching being done?  Your problem is likely in `$editedLanguage->getEnglishName()` rather than anything in your code.  Can you retrieve the data from the db directly rather than depending on that function to get it for you?

Comment: I tried using a simple doctrine query, but I got the same result. And at any rate, the first time--when I was using the object, I got a new one from the database. It seems to think the old value is still there, even though it got flushed to the database. Is there any way to output the current value without actually trying to assert anything?

Comment: Here's waht I tried: `$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT t.englishName FROM \Entities\PsnTypes t
   WHERE t.id = :id')
   ->setParameter('id', $id);` I ran the result of that query through $this->assertEquals(), but the result was the same. Should I be turning off caching, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The $this->assertEquals() will throw an error when the strings ARE NOT equal.  It is sort of  a reversed logic if you are not familiar with it.  Therefore, you will likely want to test that the changed language matches with the assertEquals.